# Map through a Javascript array of objects and return a new one satisfying a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, ecmascript-6

Having the following data structure:

```
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "View Profile",
                "href": "/profile",
                "icon": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "Manage Account",
                "href": "/manage",
                "icon": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "Other",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Access",
                "href": "/access",
            },
            {
                "name": "Give Feedback",
                "href": "/feedback",
                "icon": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It is needed a function that returns an array of objects which contains only the elements that have `name` and `href`, ignoring the ones that don't have it.

So the resulted array should be like this:

```
[
   { 
      "name": "View Profile",
      "href": "/profile"
   },
   { 
      "name": "Manage Account",
      "href": "/manage"
   }, 
   { 
      "name": "Access",
      "href": "/access"
   }, 
   { 
      "name": "Give Feedback",
      "href": "/feedback"
   }
]
```

I've tried to do it like this but without success:

```
const result = input.map(obj => obj.items).map(innerObj => innerObj.href ? ({innerObj.name, innerObj.href});
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick one liner - You flatten the results from the first map and then filter for items with href & name:

```
input.flatMap(({ items }) => items).filter(({ href, name }) => href && name)
```

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead of `map`+`flat`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the properties and return either an object or an array for getting a flat result.

```js
const
    data = [{ items: [{ name: "View Profile", href: "/profile", icon: {} }, { name: "Manage Account", href: "/manage", icon: {} }, { name: "Other", icon: {} }] }, { items: [{ name: "Access", href: "/access" }, { name: "Give Feedback", href: "/feedback", icon: {} }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ items }) =>
        items.flatMap(({ name, href }) => name && href ? { name, href } : [])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: OP doesn't want arrays in their result

Comment: @Bergi, sorry ...

Comment: That's still weird. You shouldn't return non-iterables from the `flatMap` callback. Just use `filter`, no?

Comment: @Bergi, why? filter returns the original objects, which looks like is not the wanted result. what else should i do?

Comment: Ah I didn't spot the `icon` properties were removed, that makes sense. But I'd still prefer `items.flatMap(({ name, href }) => name && href ? [{ name, href }] : [])` or `items.filter(i => i.name && i.href).map(({ name, href }) => ({ name, href }))`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `flatMap()` flattens the result by one level, next use the `filter()` to get only elements with the `href` and `name` available

```
const result = input.flatMap(obj => obj.items).filter(({href, name}) => href && name)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.